# ActiveRecord transactions not raising errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, rails-api

I've set up an ActiveRecord transaction, however when the second statement fails, it's not causing the transaction to fail. Here's my code:

```
  Contact.transaction do
    contact = Contact.create(params)
    channel = ContactChannel.create(contact: contact, phone: contact.phone)
    # ContactChannel query raises a validation error
    # puts "ERRORS: #{channel.errors.messages}" outputs the following:
    #      {:channel_key=>["has already been taken"]}
    contact # Still returns the contact that was created
  end
```

Any idea why this doesn't fail despite the validation error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`create!` instead of `create` should raise an exception, which should cause the transaction to be rolled back. It is basically a more strict version, and if no exception is raised, the transaction does not fail.

To get the reason for the transaction rollback, you can wrap your Transaction-statement in an `begin (...) rescue` - block and catch the `ActiveRecord::Rollback`- error and use its message to return the reason for the transaction failure.

Comment: Oh interesting! Is there a way to then return the error messages in that statement?

Comment: I do think so, you could do a `begin (...) rescue `-block or use the `after_rollback`-callback. You might have to experiment with that, I have not gotten around to playing with that. Maybe the community can tell you more on that.

Comment: Oh, apparently ActiveRecord reraises the exception after rolling back the transaction, I'll edit my answer to include that.

Comment: Well I ended up with this code in the controller as a result of this which doesn't look that nice: https://gist.github.com/biznickman/efe463236a3dfd33ed0dbd1459e0cd9e

Comment: I think that is actually pretty decent, nothing to add there :-)